# React-router: TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to set up routing in `Meteor` using `react-router` package and have encountered the following **`TypeError`**:

Link to image: https://postimg.org/image/v0twphnc7/

The code in I use in `main.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// Importing components
import App from './components/app';
import Portfolio from './components/portfolio/portfolio';


//Creating a route
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Router path='portfolio' component={Portfolio} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);


// Loading routes
Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(routes, document.querySelector('.universe'));
});
```

The problem that I've managed to identify is that when I define portfolio as a Simple Component it works.

```
const Portfolio = () => {
    return (
        <div className='red'>Portfolio page</div>
    );
}
```

But when I extend it from the Component is where the error comes in:

```
class Portfolio extends Component () {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>Portfolio page</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can you please explain the possible difference between "normal" and class component and why the following error appears.

Comment: Should'nt it be React.Component unless you are importing Component seperately from react.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Assuming you are importing `Component` as a `React.Component` correctly, try removing  the parenthesis after Component.

Should be:

```
class Portfolio extends Component {
```

instead of:

```
class Portfolio extends Component () {
```

If not, replace `Component`with `React.Component`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!  That was pretty easy! :) *facepalm*

Comment: why the > Component ()  means? is it because in that way it's like a function expecting the props?

Comment: Component is a class thats why

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck with this for sometime.