# Error when I compile React Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue with the code

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined
```

I think I did everything right. I even referenced
`react cannot set property of props of undefined and React-router: TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined`
was unable to figure out the error.
As a new coder I would appreciate any tips to be able to figure out this errors in the future

I am trying to create a contact us page.I am receiving a compiling error when I try to compile the Page. please help.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
// import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

export class Contact extends Component(){
     state = {
        name: '',
        message: '',
        email: '',
        sent: false,
        buttonText: 'Send Message'
    }
    render(){
    return (
        <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={ (e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
  <label class="message" htmlFor="message-input">Your Message</label>
  <textarea onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value})} name="message" class="message-input" type="text" placeholder="Please write your message here" value={this.state.message} required/>

  <label class="message-name" htmlFor="message-name">Your Name</label>
  <input onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value})} name="name" class="message-name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value={this.state.name}/>

  <label class="message-email" htmlFor="message-email">Your Email</label>
  <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value})} name="email" class="message-email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required value={this.state.email} />

  <div className="button--container">
      <button type="submit" className="button button-primary">{ this.state.buttonText }</button>
  </div>
</form>
    )
 }
 formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  
    this.setState({
        buttonText: '...sending'
    })
  
    let data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        message: this.state.message
    }
    
    axios.post('API_URI', data)
    .then( res => {
        this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm())
    })
    .catch( () => {
      console.log('Message not sent')
    })
  }
  resetForm = () => {
    this.setState({
        name: '',
        message: '',
        email: '',
        buttonText: 'Message Sent'
    })
}
}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2j5g.png)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38486303/5492956

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router: TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484490/react-router-typeerror-cannot-set-property-props-of-undefined)

Comment: why people still use Components ? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extended the component in the wrong way. `Component` is a `class` and it cannot be extended as a `function call`

**This is how you extend**

`export class Contact extends Component(){...`

**It should be**

`export class Contact extends Component {...`

Comment: Please do up if it is helpful. Thanks

Comment: can you please look at this issue of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957728/starting-node-server-js-nodemon-clean-exit-waiting-for-changes-before-rest

Answer (score 0):

To define a React component as a class, extend the built-in Component class and define a render method:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

// rather export class Contact extends Component(){

// Do this instead
class Contact extends Component {
 constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
   name: 'Wilfred'
  }
 }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.state.name}!</h1>;
  }
}
```

You can refer to their React Doc beta as of this date (02-22-2023)
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Component#component