# starting `node server.js` [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express

This application is created with React I am tying to have the user enter the is email and a message to and have the server send the message to the user email address. But when I try to send the message I receive error number 2 and I also can see in the terminal the error number 1.

I am sure I have turned the back end server but something is not going right. I am not sure how to fix this proxy issue. Maybe a look at the JSON file will help so I have added the screen shot.

I have two errors I have added screenshots so it can be easier to understand.

```
    **Error 1**
            I am having this issue with my server: 
    
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
    [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
    [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`
            
     **Error 2**
    >Proxy error: Could not proxy request /API_URI from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080.
    See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information 
    (ECONNREFUSED).
```

```
    const express = require('express');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    
    // Serve static files from the React app build directory
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
    });
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Welcome to my api');
    });
    
    app.post('/api/v1', (req, res) => {
      var data = req.body;
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          user: 'abcde@gmail.com',
          pass: '1234567',
        },
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        from: data.email,
        to: 'ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL',
        subject: 'ENTER_YOUR_SUBJECT',
        html: `<p>${data.name}</p>
                <p>${data.email}</p>
                <p>${data.message}</p>`,
      };
    
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions,
        (error, response) => {
          if (error) {
            res.send(error);
          } else {
            res.send('Success');
          }
          smtpTransport.close();
        });
    
      app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`App listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
        console.log('*************************************\n');
      });
    });
```

server.js

[image: server.js]

Error node

[image: Error node]

package JSON

[image: package json]

terminal error

[image: terminal error]

Comment: @bad_coder can you help with my error please ?

Comment: I think it's because `app.listen` is inside your route, should be outside

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which required text content is only present in images are likely to be closed as lacking enough details.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights can you please post that as an answer so I can give it a green light , it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `app.listen` is inside your `post` route, meaning the server isn't running until that route is hit, but, because your server isn't running, it can't be hit.

Move that outside your route and it should work.